# How can I await Task.WhenAll( ... ).ContinueWith( AnotherAwaitable )?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have the following bit of code -

```
await Task.WhenAll(TaskList /*List of Task objects*/);
await AnotherAwaitableMethod( );
```

This works fine and is necessary as `AnotherAwaitableMethod` relies on making certain that a task within `TaskList` is complete before executing.

However, I would like to be able to say something like

```
await Task.WhenAll(TaskList).ContinueWith( /*AnotherAwaitableMethod call?*/ );
```

Is this possible? Am I misunderstanding the purpose of `Task.ContinueWith`?

Comment: You can do something like this: `await Task.WhenAll(TaskList).ContinueWith(_ => AnotherAwaitableMethod( )).Unwrap();`. But why do you need that, if the first code already works?

Comment: well, the operative word in the question was like, not need but semantics - It's a coding preference; I'd like for the call to be on a single line.

Comment: @Will You can put it on the same line by doing `await AnotherAwaitableMethod(await Task.WhenAll(TaskList));`.

Comment: Why not `Task.WhenAll(Task.WhenAll(TaskList), AnotherAwaitableMethod())`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
  await Task.WhenAll(TaskList /*List of Task objects*/);
  await AnotherAwaitableMethod( );
```

and

```
 await Task.WhenAll(TaskList /*List of Task objects*/).ContinueWith(_ => {AnotherAwaitableMethod();}).Unwrap();
```

will act almost identically. Using ContinueWith however will give you a lot move power if you use its [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx).
One of the main reasons to use ContinueWith is when you want to execute AnotherAwaitableMethod conditionally based on the result of the first task(s) or when you want to control the context using [TaskContinuationOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That's what I wanted to know; Thank you.

Comment: You can execute the second task "conditionally based on the result of the first" very easily with await, and it is actually more difficult to do with `ContinueWith`. Moreover, passing callbacks just contorts your callstack in case there is an exception and makes debugging harder. Using callbacks like this defeats the point of having async/await in the first place.

Comment: This will return `Task<Task>`, as `AnotherAwaitableMethod` returns a `Task`. You'd need to use `Unwrap()`. There's also `TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll`. But Asad is right, you should not be favoring `ContinueWith` of any form over `await`, @Will.